# Angular 2/4 Lazy Loading of module, each time button clicked

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

The project component consists of a div that is showing google graph. 
In order to display the graph the component needs to be **refreshed each time** to get the id of the div. **Lazy Loading works fine for the first time only**.

```
{ path: 'projectSummary', loadChildren: './home/body/project-summary/summary.module#SummaryModule' },
```

Is there a way **load the component lazily each time** on button clicked

Comment: Why You need to load the same component twice??????????

Comment: to re-render the html and js

Comment: Why You need to re-render `html` and `js`???

Comment: to resign the ID to the div and by the ID will be used by js to render  a graph

Comment: maybe you can find solution by different question?

Comment: like: "dynamic html element ID in lazy loading module?"

Comment: thanks @SalimIbrogimov